# JSON HTTP object retieval in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

Apex Class -->

```
public class Json_Callout{
public static string response;  
// Pass in the endpoint to be used using the string url
public static string getContent() {
    system.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++In side the Method Get Content');
    String url = 'http://180.211.69.30:8080/JhImpl/WS/implService/upload';
    // Instantiate a new http object
    Http h = new Http();
    try {
        system.debug('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++In side the Try Block');
        // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setHeader('abc', 'abc');
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');

        // Send the request, and return a response
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        system.debug('Result==========================================='+res);
        system.debug('REsult for Variable=============================='+res.getBody());

        response = res.getStatus();
        String contact = response;
        return res.getBody();
    }
    catch(System.CalloutException ex) {
        system.debug('catch'+ex);
    }
}
}
```

Apex Page -->

```
 <apex:page Controller="Json_Callout" tabStyle="Account">

  It will be a nice to get output from the controller
  <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!"/>
  <apex:form >
    <apex:commandButton value="Go!" action="{!getContent}"/>
    </apex:form>
  <!--<apex:variable var="c" value="{!contact}" />-->
  <!--<apex:pageMessages>
  </apex:pageMessages>-->
  </apex:page>
```

How do i retrieve the Json Object , in order to Parse it.
I have system.debug the response.getBody() which is giving me the status code = 200 , that means i am able to hit the service , but how do i get the Json Object and the response so as to Parse it and also reflecting back it into the Apex Page .

I am getting the error that The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must begin with a letter and be unique, and must not include spaces, end with an underscore, or contain two consecutive underscores.

Thanks.